# How can i represent this data in array format

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Good day guys! I have a list of data which i want to hard code into a react native app but i dont know how to represent the data in an array. I hope you can help me out.

So there is a title and subtitles in the array. Here is an example

```
const [people, setPeople] = useState([{
    title: "Evidence Act", 
    id: "1",
    subtitle:[{
        part: "Introduction cc", 
        meaning: "how are you don"
    }, {
        part: "Introduction bb", 
        meaning: "how are you don"
    }]
}])
```

The above code does no work well for me. The flatlist does not map through the "part". It only displays the first part.

Please is is there a better way to represent this type of data in an array. I will really appreciate your help...

Comment: share example of hard code data

Comment: What you have to show as data in flatlist? people or subtitle?

Comment: I want to display all the data. So in screen 1 i want to show "title". Then i want to show "subtitle" in screen 2, and "parts " in screen three then "meaning" in screen 4

Comment: Share your code so can help you out

Comment: Thank you very much. Please my code is below

Comment: The flatlist does not map through the names even after writing item.part[0].name. It only display the first name.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([
      {Law: "Evidence Act", id: "1",
      part:[ {name: "Introduction cc", meaning: "how are you don"},
      {name: "Introduction bb", meaning: "how are you don"}
      
    ]

},
])
  
    return (
      <FlatList
      numColumns={1}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} 
      data={people} 
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <List >

          <ListItem onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NigLawParts', item)}>
           
              <Text  style={{
            fontSize: 20,
            }}>{item.Law}</Text>
             
          </ListItem>

          </List>
      )}





      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
```

This is what i have now. I just want to display all the item.part[0]name and item.part[0]meaning in different pages